# Cannot install ocrfeeder on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, ocr

ocrfeeder is an Ubuntu desktop application which utilises Tesseract and other OCR engines to perform OCR. I had it running OK under Ubuntu 14 but am having problems installing it under 18.04. Problem is unmet dependencies for Python components.

**Python version**

```
2.7.15~rc1-1
```

**Specific error message**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
    ocrfeeder : Depends: python-sane but it is not going to be installed
```

**Further investigation**

I individually installed all the dependent packages for python-sane based on the documentation at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-sane. These all installed OK except for python-numpy which gave the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    python-numpy : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or liblapack.so.3
```

Installing liblapack3 gave the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    liblapack3 : Depends: libgfortran4 (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
```

Installing libgfortran4 gave the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    libgfortran4 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Please don't show us edited summaries. We need to see complete input and output. 1) Please show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. 2) Please show us the complete output of `sudo apt install ocrfeeder`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04. I think the original installation was installed from an unreliable mirror with old versions of some components.